# In React Native how to Store values in session?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

**In React Native how to Store values in session ?**

I need to store login details (Username , Password) in session .

Could you Please Give any ideas.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `AsyncStorage`.

Example:

For saving:

```
AsyncStorage.multiSet([
    ["email", userInfo.email],
    ["name", userInfo.name]
])
```

For Deleting:

```
let keys = ['email', 'name'];
AsyncStorage.multiRemove(keys, (err) => {
    console.log('Local storage user info removed!');
});
```

For Getting:

```
AsyncStorage.multiGet(['email', 'name']).then((data) => {
    let email = data[0][1];
    let name = data[1][1];

    if (email !== null)
        //Your logic
});
```

Comment: `AsyncStorage` saved data in `unencrypted` form and is accessible globally. so Its not the best option to save `password`

Comment: @RaheelHasan can we not encrypt them before storing to AsyncStorage