# How to remove an item from AsyncStorage in react-native

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

How to remove an item from AsyncStorage? right now I am trying this code:

```
AsyncStorage.removeItem('userId');
```

but this is not working for me.

Comment: Try adding the callback to removeItem and console log some output to make sure everything is working properly. `AsyncStorage.removeItem('token', (err) => console.log('userId', err));`Also provide more of your code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42627947/in-react-native-how-to-store-values-in-session/42628807#42628807

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Try this:

```js
async removeItemValue(key) {
    try {
        await AsyncStorage.removeItem(key);
        return true;
    }
    catch(exception) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This is what I did, had a similar issue.It works well when you want to remove an item based on its id. make sure each item has a unique id.

```
remove_user = async(userid) => {
    try{
        let usersJSON= await AsyncStorage.getItem('users');
        let usersArray = JSON.parse(usersJSON);
        alteredUsers = usersArray.filter(function(e){
            return e.id !== userid.id

        })
        AsyncStorage.setItem('users', JSON.stringify(alteredUsers));
        this.setState({
           users:alteredUsers
        })
    }
    catch(error){
        console.log(error)
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

This looks correct, but maybe you are trying to read back from `AsyncStorage` too soon? It's asynchronous, so the change isn't applied right away and you might still see the key if you try to get it on the following line. Try to call `AsyncStorage.removeItem` with `await` or do what you want to do in the callback.

Answer (score 2):

Use `removeItem()` method to remove values from `AsyncStorage` in react.

```
try {
    await AsyncStorage.removeItem(key);
    console.log('Data removed')
}
catch(exception) {
    console.log(exception)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this delete method which removes object from array by passing index (here i called *id*)

```
async deleteData(id)  {
      try {
        this.state.item.splice(id, 1);
        await AsyncStorage.setItem("mylist",JSON.stringify(this.state.item))
        this.setState({ item: JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem("mylist")) })

      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };
```

and call this by using *onPress* method, here i am using *button* and pass *index*

```
<Button onPress={this.deleteData.bind(this,index)}>delete</Button>
```

Comment: you just saved my day, very useful answer you can use it when you work with async storage.

Answer (score 0):

This is the framework code for AsyncStorage.removeItem:

```
removeItem: function(
 key: string,
 callback?: ?(error: ?Error) => void
): Promise {
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  RCTAsyncStorage.multiRemove([key], function(errors) {
    var errs = convertErrors(errors);
    callback && callback(errs && errs[0]);
    if (errs) {
      reject(errs[0]);
    } else {
      resolve(null);
    }
  });
 });
}
```

As you can see above it requires the key(Which is name of the item you set in asyncstorage that you want to delete) and a callback function. Make sure you have the correct key and the correct params and it should work fine.

Comment: So I see this in the documentation, but I don't understand how to actually *use* it. The syntax is indecipherable to me. Can you show an example of how one would write the code to delete a item from the storage, given the key of the item that is to be deleted? Many Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Also I see many are using await.. is it possible to just use promises and .then and .catch ?

Answer (score 0):

try this for react-native

```
const deletCar = async () => {
        try {
            await AsyncStorage.removeItem('@storage_Key').then(() => {
               
                // props.navigation.navigate('same page name refresh ');   
               /* setprevCar({ carNumner: '', carModel: '' }) return  empty obj if deleted. */
            })


        }
        catch (exception) {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove the selected list :-

```
 let key =[
    'visitorId',
    'visitorMobile',
    'visitorData',
  ]

await AsyncStorage.multiRemove(key)
```